# Android Architecture code not working

Tags: android, architecture

I am trying the code from this link on Android Developers website and facing some issue:

```
    https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

    Here is my code: 

public class UserProfileFragment extends LifecycleFragment {

        private static final String UID_KEY = "uid";
        private UserProfileViewModel viewModel;
        public UserProfileFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_profile, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //        String userId = getArguments().getString(UID_KEY);
            viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserProfileViewModel.class);
            //ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MoviesDataViewModel.class);
            viewModel.init();
            viewModel.getUser().observe(this, user -> {
                Log.i("UI","Update ui");
            });
        }

    }

    public class UserProfileViewModel extends ViewModel {

        private LiveData<User> user;
        private UserRepository userRepo;

        @Inject // UserRepository parameter is provided by Dagger 2
        public UserProfileViewModel(UserRepository userRepo) {
            this.userRepo = userRepo;
        }

        public UserProfileViewModel() {

        }

        public void init() {
            if (this.user != null) {
                // ViewModel is created per Fragment so
                // we know the userId won't change
                return;
            }
            user = userRepo.getUser();
        }

        public LiveData<User> getUser() {
            return this.user;
        }

    }

public class UserRepository {
    private Webservice webservice;
    // ...
    public LiveData<User> getUser() {
        // This is not an optimal implementation, we'll fix it below
        final MutableLiveData<User> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        webservice.getUser().enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                // error case is left out for brevity
                data.setValue(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return data;
    }
}
```

The userRepo object is coming as null in UserProfileViewModel class. This code:

```
public UserProfileViewModel(UserRepository userRepo) {
            this.userRepo = userRepo;
        }
```

is not getting executed at all. I am new to Dagger2 as well. Any help will be appreciated. There is no mention about the same in the original post as well hence I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserProfileViewModel.class);

You are not using ViewModelProvider.Factory. First you should create view model factory class this where you can pass repository to ViewModel.

**ViewModelProvider.Factory**

```
@yourscope
public class UserRepositoryModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    @Inject
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Inject
    public UserRepositoryModelFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(UserProfileViewModel.class)) {
            return (T) new UserProfileViewModel(userRepository);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong ViewModel class");
    }
}
```

In activity inject view model factory

```
 @Inject
 UserRepositoryModelFactory userRepoViewModelFactory;
```

Use view model factory while instantiating ViewModel.

```
userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, userRepoViewModelFactory).get(UserProfileViewModel.class);
```

If you need more information you can check http://www.zoftino.com/android-architecture-component-viewmodel